# Desarrollo de tetris en java

Tags: java, java-swing

Me han encargado de proyecto final un tetris y no tengo idea de como hacerlo ya que no he trabajado con interfaces graficas.
Me estan pidiendo que use Jpanel y JFrame para la parte grafica, y la parte logica en una matriz.

Tengo que hacer diferentes clases, y solo tengo las dos mas basicas.

-clase punto: una para definir los puntos de cada cuadrito de los cuatro que forman a cada figura

Clase cuadro: donde uso la clase punto para hacer un solo cuadrito y dibujarlo con .drawRect()

Esta es mi clase Punto

```
package Tetris;


public class Punto {

int x,y;

public void setx(int mix){
    x=mix;
}

public void sety(int miy){
y=miy;
}

public int getx(){
    return x;
}

public int gety(){
   return y;
}

}
```

Y esta es mi clase cuadro

```
package Tetris;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;


public class Cuadro extends JPanel {
Punto p0,p1;

Cuadro(int a, int b, int i, int j)    {
p0=new Punto();
p0.setx(a);
p0.sety(b);

p1=new Punto();
p1.setx(i);
p1.sety(j);
}


public Punto getP0()
{
   return p0;
}

public Punto getP1()
{
    return p1;
}

public void movex(int i)
{
    p0.setx(i);
    p1.setx(i);
}

public void movey(int j)
{
    p0.sety(j);
    p1.sety(j);
}

public Punto getp0()
{
return p0;
}

public Punto getp1()
{
return p1;
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{    
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawRect(p0.getx(), p0.gety(), p1.getx()-p0.getx(), p1.gety()-p0.gety());
}

}
```

Y pues tengo que crear una nueva clase hacer la figura completa haciendo uso de cuatro objetos de la clase cuadro y ahí es donde no tengo idea de que hacer.

**Mi duda principal es ¿Cómo puedo heredar cuatro cuadros en mi clase figura y dibujarlos en el frame?**
Lo que si puedo hacer es colocar en el frame un solo cuadro directo de la clase cuadro, pero lo que yo necesito es colocar cuatro cuadros en mi clase figura y después colocar esa figura en el frame.

y pues a mi profesor no le entiendo nada (Porque no se explica). Asi que si me ayudaran con esa duda seria de gran ayuda para mi.

Comment: Hola Fran. Qué mal que tu profesor no te explique. Quizá deberias hablarlo con compañeros o con otros proesores del deparatmento. Esta pregunta es demasiado amplia ya que nosotros ayudamos sobre problemas concretos durante el desarrollo, no algo abierto y nada especificado. Mira [ask] y [mcve] para más info. un saludo

Comment: @Shassain creo que es mejor que en vez de darle el trabajo ya hecho, espera a que mejore la pregunta con más informacion y despues intenta resolver su problema en una respuesta siguiendo [answer]. Un saludo